An 80s horror movie with small creatures eating people
I'm looking for an 80s horror movie where one of the scenes featured a woman. I think she was a mayor because when I was younger, I was watching scary scenes from horror movies, and I saw this scene in a YouTube video. I guess it was deleted; the title was "Mayor Gets Eaten."
In this scene, she went to a public toilet, I guess, and a creature was in the toilet or somewhere near. Then it jumped at her arm and started biting it and didn't want to let go. The woman was fighting; she was winning, but I think she slipped because of a lot of her blood on the floor. Then the door shut, and there was a shot of her shoes covered in blood. She was wiggling for a while, but then started chewing noises and a mischievous laugh or something.

Probably one of the Critters or Ghoulies films.

I thought so but no i something simillar

it was like small gator or lizard ig he was on 4 lega he was small but not rly small she was wiggling her arm when it bit her it has long face if remember correct u have something on ur mind?

she could lift him if remember correct she was throwing him but then she slipped and got eaten smth like that few scenes before she tied up some man in basement or something

I think there's a scene a bit like this in The Gate, but I think it was a young(?) woman and in a bedroom(?)

woman in scene i watched was not really old she was closer to being young
